# I am unable to solve this error in My Ubuntu 12.04 '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 1050 package 'swish++'

Tags: 12.04, dpkg

When I tried to update my system and installing new program. It failed because of following error. I tried to remove Swish++, but that also failed. So currently I am not able to update/upgrade/install/uninstall/remove any packages from my system. I have tried F- Install but that is also not working.

kindly guide to solve this problem.

```
 `Depends' field, reference to `libc6':
     implicit exact match on version number, suggest using `=' instead
    dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 1050 package 'swish++':
     `Depends' field, reference to `libc6':
     version value starts with non-alphanumeric, suggest adding a space
    dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 1050 package 'swish++':
     `Depends' field, reference to `libc6': version contains ` '
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
    A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
    dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 1050 package 'swish++':
     `Depends' field, reference to `libc6':
     implicit exact match on version number, suggest using `=' instead
    dpkg: warning: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 1050 package 'swish++':
     `Depends' field, reference to `libc6':
     version value starts with non-alphanumeric, suggest adding a space
    dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/status' near line 1050 package 'swish++':
     `Depends' field, reference to `libc6': version contains ` '
```

Requested output from comment:

```
arif@arif-desktop:~$ head -n 1050 /var/lib/dpkg/status | tail -n 1
Depends: libc6 (.= 2.7), libstdc++6 (>= 4.6), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4), perl5
```

Comment: Welcome at askubuntu, I'm not quite sure what your question is. Please describe what you did and what happened. Try to give as much as information as possible. This can help to solve your question. Have fun at Askubuntu

Comment: Still waiting for Answer....

Comment: Please open a terminal and enter: `head -n 1050 /var/lib/dpkg/status | tail -n 1`. Copy the output into your question. I assume this line has something wrong in it.

Comment: arif@arif-desktop:~$ head -n 1050 /var/lib/dpkg/status | tail -n 1
Depends: libc6 (.= 2.7), libstdc++6 (>= 4.6), zlib1g (>= 1:1.1.4), perl5
arif@arif-desktop:~$

Answer (score 1):

As the output suggests, your `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file has an error in it. The line 1050 prints

```
Depends: libc6 (.= 2.7)
```

The dot  should be a greater than sign (`>`). The various package commands (`dpkg`, `apt-get` etc.) don't understand what the dot is for. They are rather strict in their syntax. You should change this to the correct value.

So open the file as user root and change the value. You can use the editor `vim`:

```
sudo vim /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

and enter the sequence `1050Gf.r>:wq`. This sequence goes to line 1050 (`1050G`), searches for a dit (`f.`), replaces it with `>` (`r>`) and saves/closes the file (`:wq`).

Another way would be `sed`:

```
sudo sed -i.bak 's,^\(Depends: *libc6 *(\.\),\1,' /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

However you could also use any graphical editor, like Geany, Gedit or others. Assuming you are using [Geany](http://www.geany.org/):

1. `gksu geany +1050 /var/lib/dpkg/status`
   This command  will first ask for your user password and afterwards open the file at line 1050. The line should begin with `Depends` and you'll find the dot after the opening braket.
2. Move the cursor to the dot and change it to `>`. So that it reads `libc6 (>= 2.7)`
3. Save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>)and close the file.
4. Update the packages with synaptic or software center. Now everything should be working as expected.

Comment: vim is not working........is there any other way to resolve it..I don't know how to use Geany or Gedit

Comment: plz explain me in asimple way...so I can try to resolve it......I had tried previous suggestions but didn't work

Comment: I explained a bit more. Does this help?